# Vacation workflow

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

We will going to develop multiple long running workflow for employees to request a vacation the scenario will be like this :

- Employee request a vacation
- get the direct manager to review
- Direct manager review the request if approved the request goes to HR Manager else the request rejected also the manager can return the request to employee for modification and then employee modify the request and forward it again.
- Hr manager review the request if approved send notification mails for employee and manager.

The Workflow should be persisted and resumed.

I looked for many online resources but I can not decide where to start from 
State machine or flowchart ??

this may be silly question but can anyone provide ant design consideration and small sample if available to follow

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you have various states and you also have moving back and forth from one state to another, I'd pick state machine. Create several states, such as:

- InReview
- Incomplete
- Approved

Then you can create a set of service contracts and expose your activities as workflow service, and then use those as triggers to move between the states. I.e. create WCF operation contract such as:

void ApproveVacation(...)

And then you would create a transition between the states InReview to Approved, which would be triggered by service call to ApproveVacation operation of your workflow/WCF service.

Comment: thanks for your reply but what if I used Workflowapplication not wcf services and if you please have a complete simple example it will be appreciated .

Comment: You need to add Send/Receive activities to your workflow and those will expose WCF endpoints based on the contracts you define (does not matter if you invoke it as workflow application).